# observeEvent for row selection in Flexdashboard

Tags: r, datatable, flexdashboard

I trying to recreate the CRUD app proposed by Chris Glur 
http://ipub.com/apps/shiny_crud01/ using Flexdashboard.

I am running into some problems when I select a row in the datatable for editing, the data elements from the selected row in the datatable is not sent to the input elements on the side panel on the left.

[image]

I am wondering if this an issue with flexdashboard not processing the section of `observeEvent` code below or if the javascript behind the datatable not processing the `observeEvent` accurately.

```
# Select row in table -> show details in inputs
  observeEvent(input$responses_rows_selected, {
    if (length(input$responses_rows_selected) > 0) {
      data <- ReadData()[input$responses_rows_selected, ]
      UpdateInputs(data, session)
    }

  })
```

This code sends the data from the selected row into the input elements in the input panel however this is not working in Flexdashboard.

Below is my complete flexdashboard code for this problem. I would greatly appreciate it someone can provide some feedback. Thanks in advance.

````
---
title: "CRUD Prototype"
author: "Missy"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:

    theme: United
    social: menu
    source_code: embed

    vertical_layout: scroll
    smooth_scroll: true
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

```

```{r}
CreateDefaultRecord <- function() {
  mydefault <- CastData(list(id = "0", name = "", used_shiny = FALSE, r_num_years = 2))
  return (mydefault)
}


# This method casts from the inputs to a one-row data.frame. We use it, for instance, when the user 
#creates a new record by typing in values into the inputs, and then clicks “Submit”

CastData <- function(data) {
  datar <- data.frame(name = data["name"], 
                      used_shiny = as.logical(data["used_shiny"]), 
                      r_num_years = as.integer(data["r_num_years"]),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  rownames(datar) <- data["id"]
  return (datar)
}


# This method takes the data as selected in the DataTable, and updates the inputs with the respective values

UpdateInputs <- function(data, session) {
  updateTextInput(session, "id", value = unname(rownames(data)))
  updateTextInput(session, "name", value = unname(data["name"]))
  updateCheckboxInput(session, "used_shiny", value = as.logical(data["used_shiny"]))
  updateSliderInput(session, "r_num_years", value = as.integer(data["r_num_years"]))
}

# This function finds the next ID of a new record. In mysql, this could be done by an incremental index, 
# automatically. And then this method could be used to fetch the last insert ID. But here, we manage the ID ourselves:


GetNextId <- function() {
  if (exists("responses") && nrow(responses) > 0) {
    max(as.integer(rownames(responses))) + 1
  } else {
    return (1)
  }
}


#Create


CreateData <- function(data) {

  data <- CastData(data)
  rownames(data) <- GetNextId()
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
  } else {
    responses <<- data
  }
}


#Read

ReadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses
  }
}


#Update

UpdateData <- function(data) {
  data <- CastData(data)
  responses[row.names(responses) == row.names(data), ] <<- data
}

#Delete

DeleteData <- function(data) {
  responses <<- responses[row.names(responses) != unname(data["id"]), ]
}



GetTableMetadata <- function() {
  fields <- c(id = "Id", 
              name = "Name", 
              used_shiny = "Used Shiny", 
              r_num_years = "R Years")

  result <- list(fields = fields)
  return (result)
}

```

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r , echo = F}

                                              shinyjs::useShinyjs()

                                              shinyjs::disabled(textInput("id", "Id", "0"))
                                              textInput("name", "Name", "")
                                              checkboxInput("used_shiny", "Used Shiny", FALSE)
                                              sliderInput("r_num_years", "R Years", 0, 25, 2, ticks = FALSE)


                                              actionButton("submit", "Submit")
                                              actionButton("new", "New")
                                              actionButton("delete", "Delete")

```

```{r}

 # input fields are treated as a group
  formData <- reactive({
    sapply(names(GetTableMetadata()$fields), function(x) input[[x]])
  })

  # Click "Submit" button -> save data
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    if (input$id != "0") {
      UpdateData(formData())
    } else {
      CreateData(formData())
      UpdateInputs(CreateDefaultRecord(), session)
    }
  }, priority = 1)

  # Press "New" button -> display empty record
  observeEvent(input$new, {
    UpdateInputs(CreateDefaultRecord(), session)
  })

  # Press "Delete" button -> delete from data
  observeEvent(input$delete, {
    DeleteData(formData())
    UpdateInputs(CreateDefaultRecord(), session)
  }, priority = 1)

  # Select row in table -> show details in inputs
  observeEvent(input$responses_rows_selected, {
    if (length(input$responses_rows_selected) > 0) {
      data <- ReadData()[input$responses_rows_selected, ]
      UpdateInputs(data, session)
    }

  })

```

Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r}

DT::renderDataTable({
    #update after submit is clicked
    input$submit
  input$new
    #update after delete is clicked
    input$delete
    ReadData()
  }, server = FALSE, selection = "single",
  colnames = unname(GetTableMetadata()$fields)[-1]
  )     

```
````

Comment: I think you may want to look at inserting an inline shinyApp or a shiny module inside of a flexdashboard. Here's the link to RStudio's page: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html

Comment: @missy morrow also posted this on DT's github and there an answer is provided: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/300#issuecomment-236648292